# If $X_{1}, X_{2}$ is a r.s. from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (Scale Family) show that $\frac{X_1}{X_2}\sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $X_{1}, X_{2}$ is a random sample from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (Scale Family) show that $\frac{X_1}{X_2}\sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$.

Here, I have been trying to use the CDF $F_{\frac{X_1}{X_2}}\left( y_{1} \right)=P\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2}\leq y_{1} \right)$. But I am confused in how to proceed.

Comment: Note that $X_1/X_2 \le y$ is the same as
$$
\Big[ X_1\le yX_2\ \&\ X_2>0 \Big] \text{ or } \Big[ X_1\ge yX_2\ \&\ X_2<0\Big]
$$
(this neglects the case where $X_2=0,$ but that has zero probability). That tells you what part of the plane to integrate over.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation), where without loss of generality $\sigma=1$ so$$f_{X_1/X_2}(z):=\int_{\Bbb R}|x_2|\tfrac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(1+z^2)x_2^2/2}dx_2=\tfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty x_2e^{-(1+z^2)x_2^2/2}dx_2=\tfrac{1}{\pi(1+z^2)}.$$

Comment: Thank you, however, I still don't understand why you assume $\sigma$=1. Can you explain?

Comment: @AlexisSandoval Because $\tfrac{X_1}{X_2}=\tfrac{X_1/\sigma}{X_2/\sigma}$ is a ratio of independent $N(0,\,1)$ variables.